# How can I use ADT on both my Mac and Linux Dev Machines

Tags: android, linux, macos, adt, dropbox

I want to have the SDK available on both machines and sync the projects via Dropbox. However, since the SDKs for Linux and Mac are different, I have to chose a different SDK folder each time when launching Eclipse. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

I actually did something similar to this a while ago. I found that managing the ADT plugins (and SDKs) separately on each machine was a better solution, since they had path dependencies. I used Google Drive (Dropbox in your case) to hold all of the projects, which was ok at syncing the projects, but tends to run into issues with all the binary files created when building projects. As my projects grew larger, this became a bad solution for keeping things in sync as there were constantly syncing issues due to the amount of files that needed to stay in sync.

The best way to really do this is to use source control to keep your projects in sync, and I strongly recommend Git over CVS or SVN. [GitHub](https://github.com/) offers free public repos and paid private repos while [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) offers free public and private repos. I moved all of my projects to Bitbucket and now have them synced between machines, backed up, have stored histories, and can be shared publicly/privately (if I want).

In my opinion you should move away from using a file syncing service and use source control, it takes a little effort up front but is well worth it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try syncing only the actual code files you create, not the project itself (i/e file1.java if you're writing in java, file2.cpp if in C++, etc).  You might have to monkey around with adding new files, but that should be as simple as importing/exporting.  You're going to have all kinds of trouble syncing paths for 2 different machines...

Otherwise try a free source control like assembla